# visudo nopasswd is not working for wget to execute shell_exec

Tags: wget, sudo, shell-exec

I have added the below line in /etc/ visudo in the bottom before (Defaults    passprompt="Password:" this line).
 ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/wget

When ever i try to with wget command, it is asking passowrd. I can download files after i use sudo command only. Can anyone help to download files without sudo command as I need to use the command in shell_exec PHP file.

Comment: try executing `/usr/bin/wget` directly plus try `which wget` to see which wget it executed

Comment: i tried "which wget" and returned /usr/bin/wget. /usr/bin/wget http://www.cinema.com.my/images/movies/2013/7wolverine200_450.jpg (this command also tried but again asking the password)

Answer (score 0):

The following works to give all users the right to execure /usr/bin/wget

```
ALL ALL=/usr/bin/wget,  NOPASSWD: ALL
```

you can then use

```
sudo wget google.com
```

Without being asked for a password